# Change logging level programmatically for multiple jobs

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, sql-server-agent, jobs, logs

I have multiple Sql Agent jobs, with multiple steps each.  For a large subset of these jobs, I want to set the logging levels to PERFORMANCE instead of BASIC -
 the logs are taking a lot of log space, and, more importantly, are causing a slowdown for other processes.

I went into SysJobSteps, but there is no column that I can update.  I am considering changing hundreds jobs so doing this manually isn't an option for me.

How do I do this using TSQL?

Here is an image of the 4 options available:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The logging level is held in the `command` column of [`msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobsteps-transact-sql). By editing the command you can set the logging level you require.  There is a system stored procedure - [`sp_update_jobstep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-update-jobstep-transact-sql) - to achieve this.

From a quick look on my local system, SSIS job steps' commands seem to be a reasonably straight-forward concatenation of labeled values. A bit of regex and some substitutions should be sufficient.

Comment: Ah, just a bit of Regex. PowerShell should do the trick.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you from the future.